# Issue with PATCH Call to SMA Gridcontrol API: "Token Invalid"

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am currently working with the SMA gridcontrol API in Python, attempting to make a PATCH call to the server to set the ActivePowerFixedLimitSettings to 0. Every time I execute this code, I encounter the same error: "token invalid." This is strange because I have several other API GET calls that work correctly with the exact same token. I have limited experience with PATCH calls, so I suspect that's where my mistake lies. Below you can find my code, as well as a link to the API documentation: https://sandbox.smaapis.de/gridcontrol/index.html.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://sandbox.gridcontrol.smaapis.de/v1/plants/****/settings/ActivePowerFixedLimitSettings"

payload = json.dumps([
    {
      "value": 0,
      "path": "/",
      "op": "replace"
    }
])

headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

FYI: The token is requested via OAuth 2.0 authentication, which seems to be working as my other calls are functioning properly. Here's the code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

client_id = '***'
client_secret = '***'
token_url = 'https://auth.smaapis.de/oauth2/token'
token_params = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}
refresh_token = None

def get_access_token():
    response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret),
        data=token_params
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_response = response.json()
        access_token = json_response.get('access_token')
        refresh_token = json_response.get('refresh_token')
        return access_token, refresh_token

    else:
        print(f"error: {response.text}")
        return None, None

access_token, refresh_token = get_access_token()

# Token refresh URL
token_params_refresh = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': refresh_token
}

def token_refresh():
    global refresh_token
    response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret),
        data=token_params_refresh
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_response = response.json()
        refresh_token = json_response.get('refresh_token')
        return refresh_token

    else:
        print(f"error: {response.text}")
        return None

refresh_token = token_refresh()

# Initiate user authorization-consent
def authorize_request():
    url = "https://async-auth.smaapis.de/oauth2/v2/bc-authorize"
    payload = json.dumps({
      "loginHint": "***"
    })
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.text

authorize_response = authorize_request()
print('Authorize response:')
print(authorize_response)
```

Please note that the token is acquired via OAuth 2.0 authentication, and the get_access_token() function handles this. Also, ensure that your access_token variable is properly defined and accessible where you're making the PATCH request.